# Call a method after __construct in finished

Tags: php, oop

Basically I have a method which I need to run when the constructor is finished (the method is called persist() and it simply saves a key which was generated during the constructor into the session). It seems simple enough, and it works - at the end of __construct I make the call to $this->persist().

The problem is that this class is subclassed many times. This causes two issues.

One, that I must remember to make the call to persist() at the end of every single subclass's __construct method. Not a huge issue but it doesn't feel very OOP, I feel like I could be dealing with this in the parent class some how and that this would be better.

Two, if a subclass is subclassed (which it is), and the __construct methods chained (i.e. parent::__construct called), the persist() method will be getting fired multiple times, once for each time the class has been subclassed. It only needs to be called once, when all construction is complete. In this scenario it doesn't really break anything because when the persist method is called for the 2nd, 3rd time etc., it simply overwrites what was persisted before. But that isn't the point, because I just feel like there must be a better way and that there are scenarios out there that would not allow for the method to be called multiple times.

Is a factory method which constructs the object and then makes the call to persist on it the only way? I can go down this route but I am just wondering if there is a way to do it without, so that the method from the parent is always called after construction.

Here is some example code:

```
session_start();
is(!isset($_SESSION["Component"])) $_SESSION["Component"] = [];

abstract Class Component
{
    private $id;
    protected $key;

    function __construct($id = NULL)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->key = [];
        $this->key["something"] = "SomeValue";
        $this->persist(); // First call
    }

    protected function persist()
    {
        if($this->id !== NULL) $_SESSION["Component"][$this->id] = $this->key;
    }
}

Class SomeComponent extends Component
{
    function __construct($id = NULL)
    {
        parent::__construct($id);
        $this->key["something-else"] = "SomeOtherValue";
        $this->persist(); // Second call
    }
}

Class SomeSpecialistComponent extends SomeComponent
{
    function __construct($id = NULL, $key = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($id);
        $this->key = array_merge($this->key, $key);
        $this->persist(); // Third call
    }
}

$my_component = new SomeSpecialistComponent(1, ["example" => true]);
```

Comment: OOP has nothing to do neither with method hooks nor with persisting entities. Knowing what are you doing is the only right way: remember what, when and where do you need to call.

Comment: Why not just remove the persist method and put the substance in the ctor of the base class. Wouldn't that solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue in favor of the factory method, mostly because you're [doing real work in the constructor](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/).  Remove the call where work is being done in the constructors (`$this->persist`) and place it in the factory:

```
class ComponentFactory
{
    const SOME_COMPONENT = 'component';
    const SOME_SPECIALIST_COMPONENT = 'specialist_component';

    public static function make($type, $id, $key = null)
    {
        switch($type) {
            case self::SOME_COMPONENT:
                $component = new SomeComponent($id);
                break;
            case self::SOME_SPECIALIST_COMPONENT:
                $component = new SomeSpecialistComponent($id, $key);
                break;
        }

        $component->persist();
        return $component;
    }
}

$component = ComponentFactory::make(ComponentFactory::SOME_COMPONENT, 42);
$specialist = ComponentFactory::make(
    ComponentFactory::SOME_SPECIALIST_COMPONENT, 
    43, 
    [
        'something' => 'SomeValue', 
        'something-else' => 'SomeOtherValue',
    ]
);
```

According to Miško Hevery (author of AngularJS and agile coach at Google) these are the warning signs of doing too much work in the constructor:

> 1. new keyword in a constructor or at field declaration
> 2. Static method calls in a constructor or at field declaration
> 3. **Anything more than field assignment in constructors**
> 4. **Object not fully initialized after the constructor finishes (watch
>      out for initialize methods)**
> 5. Control flow (conditional or looping logic) in a constructor
> 6. CL does complex object graph construction inside a constructor
>      rather than using a factory or builder
> 7. Adding or using an initialization block

Comment: I like SY's solution as it would mean that persist is always called regardless of whether the factory method is used or not, but I do feel like your answer is the correct one and it is also a very interesting read, thanks. I have a question; I have my factory methods in the class themselves i.e. Component::Get, rather than creating a separate class for the factory. Is there any reason to do it one way over the other? Also I pass the class name into the factory and use dynamically with 'new $class($key)' and __autoload, rather than hard code them into the factory. Any thoughts on this also?

Comment: No, separating out the factory from the implementation 'feels' more OOP-like to me.  The issue with doing the work in the constructor is that, if you happen to need an object at some point where that work is not done (e.g. during a unit test, or scope creep on the project) you're doomed. You cannot get an object without also performing that initialization step.

Comment: Yeah, this is the correct answer. Many thanks. Just have to be careful to always use the factory method when I need the persistence (I actually refactored all my code yesterday to using the factory method in all cases (albeit with the persist still called at the end of constructors)). I must be able to see the future :)

Answer (score 4):

Only trick I found to get something similar (except I wanted to execute things before and not after) is using a parent class with an abstract method as a new constructor :

```
abstract class RequireThings {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->constructAndPersist();
        $this->persist();
    }

    abstract function constructAndPersist();

    // You could also set this function in your children classes by the way.
    public function persist() {
        echo ' Then I persist!';    
    }


}

class UsingPersist extends RequireThings {

    public function constructAndPersist() {
        echo 'I do my things first.';
    }

}

$class = new UsingPersist();
```

Would output :

`I do my things first. Then I persist!`

If I got your problem right, it should be enough to avoid problems you are facing.

The main downside of this solution is that you have to use a new function which is supposed to be your new constructor for this type of classes. That's why I set the __constructPersist as  abstract, it forces the behavior as wanted.

Comment: You should never name your own functions with `__`, that's reserved by the language for future magic methods. Your subclasses also don't need to know that this function exists because of the persist method, only that it's "the bit of the constructor I'm allowed to extend" (you can even mark the real constructor as `final`). Naming caveat aside, this is a useful pattern.

Comment: @IMSoP I know right, I just named it that way here to make it clear that it's the concatenation of `__construct` and `persist` as an example responding to the given function names. Thanks for notifying this anyway :)

Comment: It's not, though: it's the subset of `__construct` that *isn't* `persist`. Good naming is a part of good design, so using names you know are bad in advice means you're giving bad advice (or rather, worse advice than if you use a better name).

Answer (score 1):

just create another function that you'll call before $this->persist and override that in your subclasses instead of the constructor

Comment: So I would have some method called initialise for example, which the parent class (Component in the example above) calls before persist(). And then in each subclass for the constructor I only make a call to the parent constructor and no more, but provide an override for initialise() which would be called by the parent constructor prior to persist()? Would that not mean only the very child-most class's initialise would be called as parent-but-not-top-level classes inbetween would have been overridden? Could I chain them using parent::initialise() at the top of each initialise() method?